# GNU Octave producing ans even when semicolon is specified when using vectors

Tags: octave

I'm new to GNU Octave and I've written a script that works fine, but its producing a weird output to the command line.

The script used is for plotting a graph point by point on button click.

The code is

```
x_axis = [0.00000000000000E+00,0.00000000000000E+00,0.00000000000000E+00,0.00000000000000E+00,5.00000000000000E-12,1.30000000000000E-11,1.94000000000000E-11,2.96400000000000E-11,3.37360000000000E-11,4.02896000000000E-11,4.55324800000000E-11,5.39210880000000E-11,6.06319744000000E-11,6.60006835200000E-11,7.02956508160000E-11,7.37316246528000E-11,7.51060141875200E-11,7.73050374430720E-11,8.08234746519552E-11,8.36382244190618E-11,8.81418240464323E-11,8.99432638973805E-11,9.28255676588976E-11,9.51314106681113E-11,9.69760850754822E-11,9.99275641272758E-11,1.02288747368711E-10,1.04177693961858E-10,1.07200008510895E-10,1.09617860150124E-10,1.11552141461508E-10,1.14646991559721E-10,1.17122871638292E-10,1.21084279764005E-10,1.24253406264576E-10,1.26788707465032E-10,1.30845189385763E-10,1.34090374922347E-10,1.36686523351614E-10,1.40840360838442E-10,1.42501895833173E-10,1.45160351824743E-10,1.49413881411255E-10,1.52816705080464E-10,1.53497269814306E-10,1.54586173388453E-10,1.56328419107088E-10,1.59116012256905E-10,1.61346086776758E-10,1.63130146392640E-10,1.65984641778052E-10,1.68268238086382E-10,1.70095115133045E-10,1.70825865951711E-10,1.71995067261575E-10,1.73865789357359E-10,1.75362367033986E-10,1.77756891316589E-10,1.79672510742671E-10,1.80438758513104E-10,1.81051756729450E-10,1.82032553875605E-10,1.83601829309451E-10,1.84857249656529E-10,1.86865922211852E-10,1.88472860256111E-10,1.89758410691519E-10,1.90272630865681E-10,1.90684007005012E-10,1.91342208827940E-10,1.91868770286283E-10,1.92711268619632E-10,1.93385267286310E-10,1.93924466219653E-10,1.94787184513002E-10,1.95477359147681E-10,1.96029498855424E-10,1.96912922387814E-10,1.97619661213725E-10,1.98750443335183E-10,2.00559694729516E-10,2.02007095844983E-10,2.03165016737356E-10,2.05017690165153E-10,2.07981967649628E-10,2.09167678643418E-10,2.10116247438450E-10,2.11633957510502E-10,2.14062293625784E-10,2.15033628071897E-10,2.15810695628787E-10,2.17054003719812E-10,2.19043296665451E-10,2.19839013843706E-10,2.21112161328915E-10,2.23149197305250E-10,2.24778826086317E-10,2.26082529111172E-10,2.28168453950938E-10,2.29837193822751E-10,2.31172185720202E-10,2.33308172756123E-10,2.36725752013596E-10,2.42193878825554E-10,2.46568380275120E-10,2.53567582594426E-10,2.59166944449870E-10,2.68125923418581E-10,2.82460289768519E-10,3.05395275928420E-10,3.23743264856341E-10,3.53100047141014E-10,4.00070898796491E-10,4.18859239458682E-10,4.48920584518187E-10,4.97018736613395E-10,5.73975779965729E-10,6.35541414647596E-10,7.34046430138582E-10,8.12850442531372E-10,9.38936862359835E-10,1.14067513408538E-09,1.30206575146581E-09,1.56029073927450E-09,1.97345071976841E-09,2.63450668855866E-09,3.16335146359086E-09,3.58642728361663E-09,4.26334859565785E-09,4.80488564529082E-09,5.23811528499720E-09,5.93128270852741E-09,6.48581664735158E-09,7.37307094947024E-09,8.08287439116518E-09,8.65071714452112E-09,9.55926554989064E-09,1.00000000000000E-08,1.14536774485912E-08,1.37795613663372E-08,1.75009756347307E-08,2.25009756347307E-08,2.75009756347307E-08,3.25009756347307E-08,3.75009756347307E-08,4.25009756347307E-08,4.75009756347307E-08,5.25009756347307E-08,5.75009756347307E-08,6.25009756347307E-08,6.75009756347307E-08,7.25009756347307E-08,7.75009756347307E-08,8.25009756347307E-08,8.75009756347307E-08,9.25009756347307E-08,9.75009756347307E-08,1.00000000000000E-07];
y_axis = [-9.39173350887998E-32,-1.86650535110635E-31,1.31115948364582E-27,1.94509722242530E-25,-1.00344588881891E-21,-5.87459290306659E-21,-1.37073757649753E-20,-4.86147958403305E-20,-7.63974343257361E-20,-1.71040940512147E-19,-3.38920214313857E-19,-1.18885155233808E-18,-3.51328830508339E-18,-8.78799288101173E-18,-1.88243629379682E-17,-3.51802689061712E-17,-4.49449528359159E-17,-6.79565282967628E-17,-1.34186349095581E-16,-2.31297635209485E-16,-5.71110439628175E-16,-8.08187727353700E-16,-1.44731539963045E-15,-2.29659329899228E-15,-3.32226881207743E-15,-6.07452021226282E-15,-9.77314790670134E-15,-1.42769268847667E-14,-2.64585536036781E-14,-4.29496639316416E-14,-6.31287803028352E-14,-1.17943950739760E-13,-1.92469245877504E-13,-4.25063881290420E-13,-7.89483522299793E-13,-1.28920665234410E-12,-2.84902213070563E-12,-5.29522377461008E-12,-8.65384357585056E-12,-1.91533007497040E-11,-2.59080275155903E-11,-4.27299516300553E-11,-9.51054948026229E-11,-1.77798774195455E-10,-1.99495474499103E-10,-2.43091404639964E-10,-3.34682557590070E-10,-5.57798852090487E-10,-8.32337198451749E-10,-1.14374909944538E-09,-1.91120020411426E-09,-2.85551127611928E-09,-3.92387180151988E-09,-4.43758170868350E-09,-5.43466810920640E-09,-7.50901087225516E-09,-9.66190860282403E-09,-1.44338575031994E-08,-1.96753685365158E-08,-2.21629406913249E-08,-2.43924996003962E-08,-2.84551960847752E-08,-3.62421339965087E-08,-4.36757128201692E-08,-5.84585839648811E-08,-7.30091830091753E-08,-8.67125059918094E-08,-9.26675103463482E-08,-9.77183969342209E-08,-1.06370533972462E-07,-1.13697585523745E-07,-1.26355935516070E-07,-1.37221352317618E-07,-1.46440395269411E-07,-1.62386536344951E-07,-1.76081449361409E-07,-1.87705716998312E-07,-2.07841349695580E-07,-2.25153990904328E-07,-2.55742641792671E-07,-3.12420515197923E-07,-3.64195554678131E-07,-4.09799710873070E-07,-4.89326201699816E-07,-6.21322334401833E-07,-6.75650203943832E-07,-7.18722478876752E-07,-7.83426435958378E-07,-8.72851070500037E-07,-9.06548231493498E-07,-9.31940701989342E-07,-9.68292309353881E-07,-1.01648017433132E-06,-1.03427589223822E-06,-1.05916417720008E-06,-1.09132796931090E-06,-1.11290602031335E-06,-1.12787010767833E-06,-1.14726311445438E-06,-1.16042155982867E-06,-1.16970022782536E-06,-1.18223247183124E-06,-1.19866965764282E-06,-1.22109633633903E-06,-1.23823245732513E-06,-1.26682187628956E-06,-1.29108062409592E-06,-1.33389344981185E-06,-1.41022558838021E-06,-1.54386804821518E-06,-1.65559050610987E-06,-1.84054551863630E-06,-2.14563662056096E-06,-2.27002646291102E-06,-2.47144856400291E-06,-2.80019687100178E-06,-3.34149054275745E-06,-3.78721156086594E-06,-4.52250561798966E-06,-5.12956538504310E-06,-6.13331392887164E-06,-7.81732846719364E-06,-9.22848148341832E-06,-1.15922677819807E-05,-1.56187309065232E-05,-2.25935707280579E-05,-2.85748785714530E-05,-3.35772955724184E-05,-4.19193206861019E-05,-4.88646689055068E-05,-5.45719983022503E-05,-6.39410090676521E-05,-7.16337339299082E-05,-8.42406203052840E-05,-9.45692560450757E-05,-1.02966392937475E-04,-1.16604302814647E-04,-1.23311931601159E-04,-1.23712116457864E-04,-1.23353312847230E-04,-1.22549100652487E-04,-1.21499037280975E-04,-1.20528308967738E-04,-1.19627601938410E-04,-1.18783794770588E-04,-1.17986366199978E-04,-1.17227234731004E-04,-1.16500110271064E-04,-1.15800272295338E-04,-1.15124231439077E-04,-1.14469284659222E-04,-1.13833235454863E-04,-1.13214238663767E-04,-1.12610729347588E-04,-1.12021382913759E-04,-1.11445101253981E-04,-1.10880995314033E-04,-1.10602993829452E-04];
sub_x = [x_axis(1), x_axis(2)];
sub_y = [x_axis(2), y_axis(3)];
plot(sub_x,sub_y);
hold on;
i = 2;
buttons=1;
while(buttons==1)
{
[x(1),y(1),buttons(1)] = ginput(1);
    i=i+1;
    sub_x=[x_axis(i-1) , x_axis(i)];
    sub_y=[y_axis(i-1) , y_axis(i)];
    plot(sub_x,sub_y, '.-');
}
endwhile;
hold off;
```

Now, the output it produces is like this-

```
    ans =
{
  [1,1] =  0.42028
  [2,1] =  3
  [3,1] =

     0   0

  [4,1] =

    -1.8665e-31   1.3112e-27

  [5,1] = -44.552
}
ans =
{
  [1,1] =  0.42028
  [2,1] =  4
  [3,1] =

     0   0

  [4,1] =

     1.3112e-27   1.9451e-25

  [5,1] = -43.579
}
```

I have no clue what this output means or how to prevent this from popping up.

Comment: remove the {} between while and endwhile

Comment: Sweet! That works. Could you explain why that works?

Comment: Sure, you are creating a cell array with `{` and `}` with the elements inside the brackets. the last one (-44.552 and -43.579 in your example) are for example handles returned from plot

Comment: Great! Thanks Andy. It would be cool if you could post that as an answer. It'll be really helpful for others with the same question

Comment: I'm not sure it would be *that* helpful for others, the [documentation on while loops](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.3/The-while-Statement.html) doesn't have any curly braces on the page, and I think this was more of a typo/misunderstanding of the basic syntax.

Comment: I'm absolutely with Wolfie ( I doubt that anyone with the same problem will find this here)